# Kill all the process from main after specific time

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

Below is my query. I am having problem with the bold text.
"You will write a program that uses multiple processes to compute the sum of a set of (small) positive integers.
There are two types of processes for this homework:
I). A set of "slaves" processes: Each slave process gets two small integers from its argv,  computes its sum and returns the result using the exit system call. So, a slave process is created for every sum.
II) A "master" process: This process is responsible for creating the slave processes, and coordinating the computation. Note that all the computation is done by the "slave" processes. All the numbers are provided in the command line argv. **The master process also set a timer at the start of computation to 3 seconds. If the computation has not been finished by this time, the master process kills all the slaves and then exits.** You should print an appropriate message(s) in this case. Note that the master process may have to create multiple sets of slave processes. For example, if there are 8 numbers to be added, then the master process will first create 4 slaves and get the result from them. At this point there are 4 numbers, and it creates 2.
slaves. Finally one slave is created to compute the overall sum. To make it simpler, if the number of integers to add is odd, the master adds a 0 to the list of numbers. This may happen at any step during the computation. The code for master process should be compiled separately and its executable code should be called master. The executable code for the slave process should be called slave. So, to compute the sum of the numbers 1 through 7, the command line will look like
master 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Since the results are passed around by exit system call, keep the numbers small (single digit). Each slave process prints its process id, its operands, and their sum. Each time the master gets a result from a slave, it prints the pid of the slave and the partial sum."

Comment: Your instructor is asking you to kill **processes**, not **threads**. Threads != processes.

Comment: Please change title, as it it not about threads but processes.

Comment: Please use paragraphs when writing novels.

Comment: @nneonneo Actually I wanna do it with threads.

Comment: @seereddisekhar Why? Your task specifically asks for processes. Are they not required?

Answer (score 2):

You are asked to use **processes**. It means you need to `fork` for every worker that is needed. Also

> The master process also set a timer at the start of computation to 3 seconds. If the computation has not been finished by this time, the master process kills all the slaves and then exits.

It would be best to set `alarm`, which would send you a signal `SIGALARM` and when it's received you will use `kill` on specific processes ids (you can get them from `fork`). If your workers will finish, so will your main process and alarm won't trigger.

It's somehow complicated task if you are new to multiprocess programming. Now just try creating some processes and killing them after for e.g. 3 seconds. If you will have more problems, post your code and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

1. When creating threads, store their identifiers.
2. After creating threads in `main()`, pause using e.g. `sleep(3)` or whatever.
3. Loop over the stored thread ID:s, calling [`pthread_cancel()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cancel) to kill them. Killing threads that have already terminated will cause this call to fail, but that's fine.

Comment: I have to start the timer when the threads starts computing. If all the threads doesn't complete their task with in three seconds then kill. sleep isn't same as timer(let say it as timer)

Comment: You can set `alarm`,and on receiving `SIGALARM` , kill corresponding thread.

Comment: The task is about processes - notice "You will write a program that uses multiple processes" and "Each slave process gets two small integers from its argv, computes its sum and returns the result using the exit system call". So no - using pthreads will not solve this

Comment: @zoska You mean to say I have to use fork. pthreads are not sufficient to do this.

Comment: @seereddisekhar I meant, the task asks you precisely to use multiprocess not multithreaded program. So it's not that `pthreads` aren't sufficient - `pthreads` aren't required for this task.

Comment: And using `pthread_cancel` is really a bad idea if you're not 100% sure what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i get your question right. You may want to start a helper thread for each worker thread that does the computing. Pass the tid of the worker thread to its helper thread and let the helper thread sleep for 3 seconds and then check if the worker thread has exited and if not just kills it.
Or alternatively if you have a dedicated timer module/task, you could start a timer for each worker thread.

Comment: it is if we are talking about linux

Comment: Don't confuse inexperienced programmer - using threads does not equal using processes even in Linux (though from system point of view they are almost the same).

Comment: the OP didnt mention process at all. it was asking how to kill all threads in the process before the UPDATE.

Comment: yes, I saw the title BEFORE the update (you can see my comment about it), but still the bolded text says `The master process also set a timer at the start of computation to 3 seconds. If the computation has not been finished by this time, the master process kills all the slaves and then exits.` - soooo, it WAS about processes from the very beginning. Also you should answer to this question referencing whole text, not only one sentence.

Comment: you should read the post before update which didnt mention process at all.